# SKScene's update function appears to not work

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I'm a mega-noob to SpriteKit / iOS dev, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

What I'm trying to do is have a small game presented in a SwiftUI View. Everything works mostly perfect, except that for some reason the update() function in my GameScene class doesnt function at all.

Sprites will still animate and move as normal, but I'm not able to add any further logic to them.

For example, the following will never print out 'hello world':

```
class GameScene: SKScene
{
    let loam = Loam() //little sprite character class
    //sets up scene
    override func didMove(to view: SKView)
    {
        let skView = view
        //loads game scene
        let scene = SKScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        scene.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9412, green: 0.8274, blue: 0.7372,alpha: 0.5)
    
        scene.addChild(loam.loam)
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
    //called before each frame is rendered
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)
    {
        print("hello world")
    }
}
```

Am I using update() wrong? Is there some sort of clash between SwiftUI's SpriteView and SKScene?

Edit: I've found that removing

```
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

allows update() to work- but then it doesn't render any sprites / animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`didMove(to view: SKView)` is called when your `GameScene` is presented in an `SKView`, so your code is presenting another `SKScene` (which is not `GameScene`), *as soon as* `GameScene` is presented, and you have added the `Loam` sprite to this new scene.

Whatever is responsible for calling `update` didn't even get a chance to call your `GameScene`'s `update` method, before you told it to present a new `SKScene`. As a result, that new scene's `update` is called instead.

Now you should understand why removing `skView.presentScene` causes your `GameScene`'s `update` to be called. And since you added `Loam` to the new scene, which is now not presented, you don't see it.

You should not need to create a new scene at all. You are already in one. Just add `Loam` to `self`:

```
anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9412, green: 0.8274, blue: 0.7372,alpha: 0.5)
addChild(loam.loam)
```

Comment: This clears up all the confusion, thanks! Got it to work after hours of trial and error :)